# Not calling a static method if another thread is already called it

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, concurrency

I have a static method that I am interested in returning immediately if another thread has called it.
E.g.

```
public static void parseNetworkData() {  
   if(isRunning) {  
     return;
   }  
   // get and cache network data  
   // for use  
}
```

I don't really want to synchronize the method because if the network call is already done I don't want the other thread to do it as well.
Now I am not sure about the following:
What is the best way to define/handle `isRunning` taking into account that this is a static method?
Should I convert this to an instance method?

Comment: If the method is invoked by one thread while another thread is running in it, what is it expected to return?

Comment: @JohnBollinger:You are right. This is confusing. The idea is that the code is supposed to update something and the return value is not really needed in all cases. I will  update OP

Comment: You could just synchronize the method and make a static instance variable that keeps track of whether or not parseNetworkData() ran (a boolean). And set the boolean to false again when you need to run it again

Comment: make the flag volatile and static

Comment: @CSK:But the other thread doesn't need to block for the other to finish

Comment: @Jim I had a similar program where I would check to see if a boolean was set before executing the method. If the boolean was set, I would immediately return, otherwise I immediately set the boolean and then run the rest of the method. Set the boolean to false as the last line of the method.

Comment: @blahfunk:So the boolean was static? In that case is the method a candidate for instance instead of static?

Comment: @Jim the boolean is global to the class. Just check, set, change that.

Comment: @Jim it doesn't block other threads

Answer (score 4):

> I have a static method that I am interested in returning immediately if another thread has called it.

That sounds highly suspect to me, but you can do it.  That the method is `static` doesn't affect the situation very much, but any way around you *do* need to apply synchronization or a concurrency support object to manage interaction between threads.  In this case, a `java.util.concurrent.ReentrantLock` could conveniently provide what you need:

```
class MyClass {
    private static ReentrantLock networkDataLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void parseNetworkData() {  
        if (!networkDataLock.tryLock()) {
            // a different thread has the lock
            return;
        }
        try {
            // get and cache network data  
            // for use  
        } finally {
            // If the lock was successfully acquired then it must be
            // unlocked without fail before the method exits
            networkDataLock.unlock();
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why is it suspect?

Comment: @Jim, given that two or more threads want the method's work to be performed, it is reasonable to insist that only one thread actually does the work.  It is suspect, however, that you suppose the other threads can usefully continue before the work is in fact completed.  Suspect, but not out of the question.

Comment: @Jim, if the threads *can* usefully continue, at least for a time, then maybe you want to look into returning a `Future` that they can use to wait for the result, if necessary, when they are finally ready to use it.

Comment: To give you more context one thread is doing something that gets data from network if nothing in cache/caches/shows to UI. The other thread periodically gets data and update the cache in the background. So there is  a case that the "job" of the background thread would be done by the other "UI" let's say thread. So the other thread just skips as it would do the call in the next periodic run. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jim, no, that seems broken.  It is true that if the periodic update thread finds that the UI thread is already running the method, then it could reasonably just skip the update, but what if it's the other way around?  The UI thread needs some data that are not cached, and the periodic update thread is in the process of getting them.  Then the UI thread needs to *wait* until the data are available, but it will not do so under the scheme you propose.

Comment: @Jim, it would be better to rely always on the periodic update thread to get the data.  If the UI thread discovers that it needs data that are not yet available, then it wakes up the update thread and waits for it to finish its job.

Comment: I can not control when the periodic update would run and the periodic update just runs this method. For your proposal to work I would need to have a way to skip an update which currently is not possible. Because without skipping we still end up with the same problem right?

Comment: @Jim, it's *your* software.  Of course you can control when the update runs.  And if only one thread ever runs the update then you never have to worry about excluding other threads at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Lock`:

```
public static void parseNetworkData() {
    if(lockObj.tryLock()) {
       //Perform method stuff
       lockObj.unlock();
    }
}
```

If the lock is already locked, nothing will happen. Lock would be a `private static final` variable, I think.

Answer (score 0):

make the flag volatile and static

```
volatile static boolean isRunning
```